# Accessing Media From a Linux Server Anywhere

Tags: media, tunnel

I have a linux media server at home. What I'd like to do is to access the media from school in a way that makes sense. For instance, I'd like to play my music (probably in iTunes or VLC) and watch videos (in VLC).

I was looking at a way to try and tunnel samba through SSH/putty, but I couldn't get it to work.

The computers that I'd want to stream from are locked down, so I can't *install* any software. They do, however, have VLC, itunes, and a few other apps. I can run portable apps and install programs that don't need admin privileges.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net) is a alright option, I've used it for years when traveling for work to play music off my home server.